# omp parallel for no optimization achieved for quadratic sieve

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to implement parallel quadratic sieve using open mp. In sieving phase, I am using log approximations to check the divisibility. This is my code.

```
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule (dynamic) num_threads(4)
    for (int i = 0; i < factorBase.size(); ++i) {
        const uint32_t p = factorBase[i];
        const float logp = std::log(factorBase[i]) / std::log(2);

        // Sieve first sequence.
        while (startIndex.first[i] < intervalEnd) {
            logApprox[startIndex.first[i] - intervalStart] -= logp;
            startIndex.first[i] += p;
        }

        if (p == 2)
            continue; // a^2 = N (mod 2) only has one root.

        // Sieve second sequence.
        while (startIndex.second[i] < intervalEnd) {
            logApprox[startIndex.second[i] - intervalStart] -= logp;
            startIndex.second[i] += p;
        }
    }
```

Here `factorbase` and `logApprox` are `std::vectors` initialized as follows

```
std::vector<float> logApprox(INTERVAL_LENGTH, 0);
std::vector<uint32_t> factorBase;
```

Whenever, I run this code and compare the running time, there is no much difference between sequential and parallel run. What are some optimizations that can be done? I am a beginner in openmp and any help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Use a profiler to identify the bottleneck then analyse the bottleneck then eliminate the bottleneck.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting task you have! Thanks!

Decided to make my own implementation with very many optimizations.

I achieved **20.4x** times boost compared to your original code (your code gives 17.86 seconds, my gives 0.87 seconds). Also I used **2x** times less memory for sieving compared to your algorithm, while achieving same goal.

To make comparison I simplified your code in such a way that it still does almost same thing and runs exactly same time, but looks much more simple:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for
for (size_t i = 0; i < factorBase.size(); ++i) {
    auto const p = factorBase[i];
    float const logp = std::log(p) / std::log(2);
    
    while (startIndex[i] < logApprox.size()) {
        logApprox[startIndex[i]] += logp;
        startIndex[i] += p;
    }
}
```

You can see that I leaved only single sieve loop, second one does same thing and not necessary for demonstration, so I removed it. Also I removed `startInterval` as it is irrelevant to speed demonstration. And for simplicity I did `+=` of logarithm instead of yours `-=`.

One important notice regarding your algorithm is that it doesn't do any synchronization, it means that different cores of CPU may write to same entry of `logApprox` array hence give wrong result.

And as I have measured this wrong result happens once or twice per hundred million entries of logApprox array. My optimized code overcame this limitation and did correct synchronization besides doing all speed optimizations.

I did following improvements to gain **20x** times speedup:

1. I split whole array into blocks, approximately 2^13 elements in size. Each group of blocks is processed by separate thread/CPU-core hence no synchronization of threads is needed. Besides avoiding synchronization what is very important is that 2^13 block fits fully into L1 or L2 cache of CPU, hence speeds up things a lot.
2. Each block of 2^13 is processed for all possible primes. To keep track of which offsets of what primes are needed I created a special ring buffer of 2^7 size, this ring buffer is indexed with block number modulo 2^7 and keeps track which primes with which offsets are needed for each block (modulo 2^7).
3. I have as many threads as there are CPU cores. For each thread I precompute starting offsets of all primes for this thread, these starting offsets are computed through modular arithmetics based on `startIndex` array that you provided in your original code.
4. To speedup even more instead of `float` logarithm I use integer logarithm, which is based on `uint16_t`. This integer logarithm is computed as `uint16_t integer_log = uint16_t(std::log2(p) * (1 << 8) + 0.5);`. Besides increasing speed of computing `+=` for integer logarithms, they also decrease occupied memory **2x** times. If for some reason uint16_t logarithm is not enough for you then please replace `using ILog2T = u16;` with `using ILog2T = u32;` in my code, but this will double amount of used memory.

My code output following to console:

`time_simple 17.859 sec, time_optimized 0.874 sec, boost 20.434, correct_ratio 0.999999993`

Time simple is time of your original code for sieving array of size 2^28, time optimized is my code for same array, boost is how much my code is faster (you can see it is 20x times faster). Correct ratio says if there are any errors in your code, due to absence of multi-core synchronization (as you can see sometimes it is less than 1.0 hence there are some errors).

Full optimized code below:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/rWeG9G6fv)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <mutex>

#include <omp.h>

#define ASSERT_MSG(cond, msg) { if (!(cond)) throw std::runtime_error("Assertion (" #cond ") failed at line " + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "! Msg: '" + std::string(msg) + "'."); }
#define ASSERT(cond) ASSERT_MSG(cond, "")
#define OSTR(code) ([&]{ std::ostringstream ss; ss code; return ss.str(); }())
#define COUT(code) { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(cout_mux); std::cout code; std::cout << std::flush; }
#define LN { COUT(<< "LN " << __LINE__ << std::endl); }
#define DUMP(var) { COUT(<< #var << " = (" << (var) << ")" << std::endl); }

using u16 = uint16_t;
using u32 = uint32_t;
using u64 = uint64_t;
using ILog2T = u16;
using PrimeT = u32;

std::mutex cout_mux;

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> GenPrimes(size_t end) {
    thread_local std::vector<T> primes = {2, 3};
    while (primes.back() < end) {
        for (T p = primes.back() + 2;; p += 2) {
            bool is_prime = true;
            for (auto d: primes) {
                if (u64(d) * d > p)
                    break;
                if (p % d == 0) {
                    is_prime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (is_prime) {
                primes.push_back(p);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    primes.pop_back();
    return primes;
}

void SieveA(std::vector<float> & logApprox, std::vector<PrimeT> const & factorBase, std::vector<PrimeT> startIndex) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < factorBase.size(); ++i) {
        auto const p = factorBase[i];
        float const logp = std::log(p) / std::log(2);
        
        while (startIndex[i] < logApprox.size()) {
            logApprox[startIndex[i]] += logp;
            startIndex[i] += p;
        }
    }
}

size_t NThreads() {
    //return 1;
    return std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
}

ILog2T LogToI(double x) { return ILog2T(x * (1ULL << (sizeof(ILog2T) * 8 - 8)) + 0.5); }
double IToLog(ILog2T x) { return x / double(1ULL << (sizeof(ILog2T) * 8 - 8)); }

double Time() {
    static auto const gtb = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - gtb).count();
}

std::string FloatToStr(double x, size_t round = 6) {
    return OSTR(<< std::fixed << std::setprecision(round) << x);
}

double SieveB(std::vector<ILog2T> & logs, std::vector<PrimeT> const & primes, std::vector<PrimeT> const & starts0) {
    auto const nthr = NThreads();
    std::vector<std::vector<PrimeT>> starts(nthr, std::vector<PrimeT>(primes.size()));
    std::vector<std::vector<ILog2T>> plogs(nthr, std::vector<ILog2T>(primes.size()));
    std::vector<std::pair<u64, u64>> ranges(nthr);
    size_t constexpr block_log2 = 13, block = 1 << block_log2, ring_log2 = 6, ring_size = 1ULL << ring_log2, ring_mask = ring_size - 1;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<u32, u32>>>> ring(nthr, std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<u32, u32>>>(ring_size));
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t ithr = 0; ithr < nthr; ++ithr) {
        size_t const nblock = ((logs.size() + nthr - 1) / nthr + block - 1) / block * block,
            begin = ithr * nblock, end = std::min<size_t>(logs.size(), (ithr + 1) * nblock);
        ranges[ithr] = {begin, end};
        for (size_t i = 0; i < primes.size(); ++i) {
            PrimeT const p = primes[i];
            size_t const mod0 = begin % p, mod = starts0[i] < mod0 ? p + starts0[i] - mod0 : starts0[i] - mod0;
            starts[ithr][i] = mod;
            plogs[ithr][i] = LogToI(std::log2(p));
            ring[ithr][((begin + starts[ithr][i]) >> block_log2) & ring_mask].push_back({i, begin + starts[ithr][i]});
        }
    }
    auto tim = Time();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t ithr = 0; ithr < nthr; ++ithr) {
        auto const [begin, end] = ranges[ithr];
        auto const [bbegin, bend] = std::make_tuple(begin / block, (end - 1) / block + 1);
        auto const & cstarts = starts.at(ithr);
        auto const & cplogs = plogs.at(ithr);
        auto & cring = ring[ithr];
        std::decay_t<decltype(cring[0])> tmp;
        size_t hit_cnt = 0, miss_cnt = 0;
        for (size_t iblock = bbegin; iblock < bend; ++iblock) {
            size_t const cbegin = iblock << block_log2, cend = std::min<size_t>(end, (iblock + 1) << block_log2);
            auto & ring_cur = cring[iblock & ring_mask];
            tmp = ring_cur;
            ring_cur.clear();
            for (auto [ip, off]: tmp)
                if (off >= cend) {
                    //++miss_cnt;
                    ring_cur.push_back({ip, off});
                } else {
                    //++hit_cnt;
                    auto const p = primes[ip];
                    auto const plog = cplogs[ip];
                    for (; off < cend; off += p) {
                        //if (8192 - 10 <= off && off <= 8192 + 10) COUT(<< "logs.size() " << logs.size() << " begin " << begin << " end " << end << " bbegin " << bbegin << " bend " << bend << " cbegin " << cbegin << " cend " << cend << " iblock " << iblock << " off " << off << " p " << p << " plog " << plog << std::endl);
                        logs[off] += plog;
                    }
                    if (off < end)
                        cring[(off >> block_log2) & ring_mask].push_back({ip, off});
                }
        }
        //COUT(<< "hit_ratio " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6) << double(hit_cnt) / (hit_cnt + miss_cnt) << std::endl);
    }
    return Time() - tim;
}

void Test() {
    size_t constexpr len = 1ULL << 28;
    std::mt19937_64 rng{123};
    auto const primes = GenPrimes<PrimeT>(1 << 12);
    std::vector<PrimeT> starts;
    for (auto p: primes)
        starts.push_back(rng() % p);
    ASSERT(primes.size() == starts.size());
    double tA = 0, tB = 0;
    std::vector<float> logsA(len);
    std::vector<ILog2T> logsB(len);
    {
        tA = Time();
        SieveA(logsA, primes, starts);
        tA = Time() - tA;
    }
    {
        tB = SieveB(logsB, primes, starts);
    }
    size_t correct = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        //ASSERT_MSG(std::abs(logsA[i] - IToLog(logsB[i])) < 0.1, "i " + std::to_string(i) + " logA " + FloatToStr(logsA[i], 3) + " logB " + FloatToStr(IToLog(logsB[i]), 3));
        if (std::abs(logsA[i] - IToLog(logsB[i])) < 0.1)
            ++correct;
    }
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << "time_simple " << tA << " sec, time_optimized " << tB << " sec, boost " << (tA / tB) << ", correct_ratio " << std::setprecision(9) << double(correct) / len << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    try {
        omp_set_num_threads(NThreads());
        Test();
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
time_simple 17.859 sec, time_optimized 0.874 sec, boost 20.434, correct_ratio 0.999999993
```

Comment: Note that calling `omp_set_num_threads` doesn't guarantee that the OpenMP runtime will use exactly the specified number of threads. You should use `omp_get_num_threads` in the parallel region.

Comment: @Laci Is there any way to force OpenMP to use exactly given amount of threads? Even if given amount is greater than amount of cores.

Comment: if you disable dynamic adjustment of the number of threads by `omp_set_dynamic(0)` and make sure that the return value of `omp_get_thread_limit()` (note that the user can change it by setting the `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` environmental variable) is bigger or equal to the number of requested threads then you will get as many threads as you requested. The exact procedure to determine the number of threads used in a parallel region can be found [here](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu35.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should turn the schedule to static and give it chunk-size (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-loop-scheduling).

A small optimization should be :

outside of the big FOR loop, declare a const and initialize it to 1/std::log(2), and then inside the FOR loop, instead of dividing by std::log(2), do a multiplication of the previous const, division is very expensive in CPU cycles.